# jquery imagesLoaded and masonry

Tags: jquery

So on my gallery page, I'm using jQuery masonry after loading my images with ajax. When I put my call to masonry inside a $(window).load function, masonry works, except for when the page is cached, and that's where the problem comes in.

To get around it, I tried using imagesLoaded, but it's not working for some reason. Masonry executes before the images are loaded.

```
var $container = $('#container');
$container.imagesLoaded( function($images){
console.log($images.length + " images have been loaded");
   $container.masonry({
        // options
        itemSelector : '.box'
   });
});
```

Any idea why that might be the case or what I could do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running all inside a document ready? http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I have tried it in a document ready block and out of a document ready block. Doesn't work either way.

Comment: Could it possibly have to do with the fact that I'm loading it with ajax?